# saving data model object array in realm saves only 1 property , rest of the properties i don't see in realm studio

Tags: ios, swift, realm

i am saving data model object array in realm, but it saves only 1 property , rest of the properties i don't see in realm studio.

find attached screenshots for reference.
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: when i tried to print newmessage array in realm.add(newmessages), it has only 1 property. but when i inspect it before write it had 4 properties.

Answer (score 0):

solved, i forgot to add @objc before data model properties.

if someone is facing same error then this fix will help.